# Recording clicked Grid View column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view in a asp page which have a hyperlink field,say,CustomerID which navigates user to various webpages. The value of the CustomerID in the grid view can have duplicate values. So, what I want is how to record all the clicked values in the CustomerID or the hyperlink?
Please suggest solution such that the solution is viable for multiple hyperlink column in gridview each navigation to different webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of gridview bind columns and pass them as parameters in url and retrieve in other page as Request.QueryString[] collection.

Eg

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Details.aspx?CustomerID={0}&Name={1}&Country={2}",
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("CustomerID").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Country").ToString())) %>'
                    Text="View Details" />
            </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```